# How to allow a motor to free spin?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, driver, back-emf

In my circuit my motor terminals are connected to the output of a VNH5019A motor driver https://www.pololu.com/product/1451. When the circuit is no longer powered I want to allow the user to freely rotate the motor (a dc motor) output shaft (which in my application has a load attached to it that I want the user to be able to move if power has disappeared). Currently if I rotate the motor fast in one direction and then suddenly change direction I can feel a "resistance" to the movement in the new direction. I assume this is because the motor is generating a voltage which opposes the movement in the new direction. Can anyone explain to me what is happening and suggest a modification to my circuit that would prevent this from happening?

Comment: You will always feel a "resistance" because of the moving mass. It's not possible to drop the inertia to zero in zero time.

Comment: Hi @Janka, thanks for your reply. I don't think the resistance I'm feeling is as a result of the moving mass as it immediately goes away if (whilst no power is connected) I briefly short the terminals of the motor. That's why I think it's due to the motor building up a voltage which opposes the movement in the new direction.

Comment: Do you feel the same if the motor is not connected with leads not touching each other?

Comment: Hi @Marko, yes even if I disconnect the motor from my circuit and with no leads touching each other and if I just have a lever (so effectively no mass) on the output shaft which I move quickly in one direction and then suddenly in the opposite direction I feel a large resistance - as if the motor is breaking. I don't seem to feel this if I only move the motor slowly in one direction and then slowly change direction.

Comment: In such case, Janka was right. It's so called moment of inertia.

Comment: Hi @Marko, the resistance I'm talking about also doesn't seem to dissipate until I short the terminals of the motor, the motor can then move freely in the new direction.

Comment: Shorting the terminals should increase the rotational resistance in any PM motor, or any externally excited DC motor with a bit of residual magnetism..

Comment: Hi @R Drast yes you're correct but I'm only briefly shorting the terminals once I feel the resistance in the motor. This seems to discharge it and enable it to free spin again. I don't leave the terminals shorted.

Comment: When you short the terminals of the motor, you turn it into a generator because the outer voltage is smaller than the internal voltage, which is directed by the speed. This will turn the energy stored in the inertia into heat, mostly inside the motor windings because your outer resistance is near zero. It's okay for smaller motors and if you do it seldomly. Else you need an external resistor. It will drop inertia faster than friction alone, of course, but not faster than just holding/reversing it mechanically.

Comment: What type of motor... do you have specs for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are noticing it is worse at higher speeds will be because of the [fly-wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flywheel) effect. The energy stored in the rotating core if proportional to the square of the angular velocity... So twice as fast = four times the energy.

[image]
Momentarily shorting the leads will cause the motor to brake rapidly dissipating much of that energy as heat in the coil.

Comment: Hi @Trevor do you know of any circuit modification I can make to remove its effect?

Comment: @user1242670 it's a mechanical effect so no. If you want it to stop and reverse more quickly you wold need to use your circuitry to actively brake it.. i.e apply a reverse voltage using a circuit capable of handling the back currents.

Comment: @user1242670 or use a motor that has a lower moment of inertia.